# Joomla Site Resizing (Same Res + Same Browser)

Tags: templates, joomla, sizing

Currently working on a website for a small business. I am running the latest version of Joomla along with the Sienna template from Rockettheme.

The issue I am facing is going back and forth with the owner to get the right placement for everything, yet what he is seeing is different from me, often the text is a different size or my screen cuts off long before his while viewing the page.

We both have the same resolution monitors along with both using FireFox (Not my browser of choice but he uses it). He hasn't zoomed in the browser or anything like that just unsure what it could be.

Unable to link site as its down and cant really provide screenshots but from what I have said it should give you some idea of what I mean.

While a lot of the modules are based on percentage width, more just seems to fit on his screen to mine.

Any ideas of what it could be? appreciate the assistance

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clear the Joomla cache and possibly your web browser caches to ensure you are both looking at the most recent version of the website.

RocketTheme templates should render a very similar experience across recent versions of popular web browsers and across different platforms although Chrome does seem to render text sizes slightly different to the others and IE often seems to do it's own thing.